# AWS API Gateway - error 403 on resource not found

Tags: aws-api-gateway, swagger-ui

It seems an `HTTP` response of `403` is accepted as the norm and correct handling of any calls made to a resource or endpoint that does not exist on an API Gateway setup ([this post](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=192977)).

Example: a call to a non-existing endpoint on my Gateway would be;

- GET -- https://{{MyGatewayDomain}}/api/v1/blah

This would return a `403 forbidden`. Which can be rather confusing and misleading.

I'd like to know if anyone has managed to configure their API Gateway so that any call to a non-existing endpoint / resource, returns what I would have thought is a correct response of a 404?

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**

As per `bejos-aws`'s suggestion, I am able to override the default behaviour of the `403 Missing Authentication Token` however, this will not solve my issue as then all the valid `403` errors would return a `404` response which is incorrect.

Also, my issue is regarding a `403 forbidden` which doesn't exist in the default responses in the AWS `Gateway Response`'s list (and even if it did, that wouldn't help).

Seems this is just not possible?

Answer (score 0):

This is not currently a feature of API Gateway. However, there is a workaround. Using Gateway Responses, you can override the `403 Missing Authentication Token` response with a `404` and supply whatever message you want as a response.

Note, this only works when the API **stage** is valid:

So if your API is deployed to a stage named **v1**

`https://{MyGatewayDomain}/api/v1/somepath`

And the caller supplies the wrong stage

`https://{MyGatewayDomain}/api/invalidStage/somepath`

Then the API will still respond with `403 Forbidden`

Comment: Wouldn't this then mean that any call to a valid endpoint that has an invalid token will get a 404? Which would then break that response?
Also, i noticed that my error is `403 forbidden` and there is no `Gateway Response` for that.

Comment: Yes it would. Unfortunately, there isn't a clean-cut solution to what you want to do.

Comment: I'm hoping someone from AWS will have some insight on this, hence, I updated my query. Thanks for trying though.

Comment: I am from AWS, hence, the username with the **aws** suffix . `403 Forbidden` occurs when the **stage** cannot be found. If you're using a custom domain to serve your API, you can simply leave the **Path** attribute of your **Base Path Mapping** empty -- doing this ensures that the stage is always correct. At this point, you will still receive a `403 Missing Authentication Token` for non-existent paths, but as mentioned above, you can override that using Gateway Responses.

Comment: Thanks, but that still won't solve the issue, meaning each `403 Missing Authentication Token` I get will return a 404, even if it's a valid endpoint but incorrect Token (when you need to get the 403). Is this something that will be changing in future?

Comment: Sorry to hear that this isn't going to work for you. An explanation can be found here: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=710158#710158

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the API Gateway uses the authorization token to handle AWS auth.

The solution for me was to change the authorization header to something different than the default one (`Authorization`). So I ended up using `Authorization-Token` instead.

Now that I'm not sending the default "Authorization" header to unexisting resources I get a 404 instead of a 403. And if I send an invalid token to a valid resource I get the proper error message with a 403 HTTP status code.

You just need to configure your authorizer to use the custom header:

[image: AWS API Gateway UI]

So my requests look like this:

```
curl --location 'https://my-endpoint.com/dev/users' \
--header 'Authorization-Token: MY_TOKEN'
```

This worked for me in both cases, using a Cognito and a Lambda authorizer.